# Reactjs materialize - how to center content in navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, materialize

I'm trying to make a navbar using the materialize framework in my react project, and would like to have the first set of links sitting in the center of the navbar, and the second set on the right side of the navbar.  I'm not sure how to do this - the helper classes "left" and "right" are working, however when I try to "center" my links, it defaults to the left side of the navbar.  Here is the code I'm working with...

```
 <div className="App">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper purple lighten-3">
        //I would like these links in the center
        <ul class="center">
          <li>
            <a href="sass.html">People</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="badges.html">Places</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        //I would like these links on the right
        <ul class="right">
          <li>
            <a href="sass.html">Sass</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="badges.html">Components</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

I've also added some css recommended on a similar post:

```
.nav-wrapper.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Here's my sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-buck-ktzxe?file=/src/App.js

Wondering if anyone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning, the same way Materialize uses it for centering the `.brand-logo`

```
ul.center {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/mdewGyw).

Here are the styles [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#center) uses to center the `.brand-logo`:

```
nav .brand-logo.center {
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

nav .brand-logo {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make all your links in center, you need to use `center` class on `div` instead on `ul`

```
<div class="nav-wrapper center purple lighten-3">
```

To keep your right side links on right side, you can use position `absolute`

```
.right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that works however now all my links are in the center.  I apologize, my question was unclear.  I would still like to keep the second set of links on the right side.  I will edit my question